# btex \begin{align} ...\end{align} etex METAPOST issue

Tags: metapost

I seem to be having trouble getting my code to carry out any amsmath command with the btex--etex environment in a metapost file. The appropriate packages are defined withint my tex file, so I really have no idea what the problem is!

I will appreciate any help!

This is my mp code:

```
outputtemplate:="%j%c.mps";
beginfig(1)
defaultscale := 10pt/fontsize(defaultfont);
u:=1.1cm;
path p; p:=(0.1cm,u)--(0.1cm,u+0.5cm);
pair A;
A:=(0.8cm,0);
drawarrow p;
draw unitsquare scaled 1cm withpen pencircle scaled 0.5;
draw (-0.01cm,0)..(-0.01cm,2cm) dashed evenly scaled 0.8 withpen pencircle scaled 0.8 withcolor red;
draw (0,-0.01cm)..(2cm,-0.01cm) dashed evenly scaled 0.8 withpen pencircle scaled 0.8 withcolor red;
%drawarrow p;
for i=0 upto 2:
drawarrow p shifted (i*A/2);
endfor;
label.ulft(btex \begin{align}\sqrt{3} \\ u_{r}=0\end{align} etex, origin );

endfig;
bye
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Metapost use TeX by default to compile the labels, even if you ask it to use LaTeX instead it does not now about `align`, it is missing the `amsmath` package. Try adding this

```
verbatimtex
%&latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
etex
```

at the start of your Metapost file.

BTW: you may want to use `align*` instead, or even just the `matrix` env inside a `$...$`, using an environment is overkill in this case.

Comment: I'd use `$\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}$`, because a display environment doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Thank you. It works. It would have helped if I had a proper look at the manual beforehand too!

Comment: It's often easier to put two separate labels instead of a stack.